# How to retrieve data from responseJSON in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how could I use Jquery to make a post request to the fandom's API and get data from the request's responseJSON?

When I use this code:

```js
$.post(
"https://drednotio.fandom.com/api.php",
{
    action: "query",
    format: "json",
    list: "allpages",
    apfrom: "a",
    aplimit: "500",
    token: "fa5fed4cd6bdb8bd8b901075ec59fa39+\\",
    bot: "true",
},
function (data) {
    var response = jQuery.JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(data);
}
);
```

I get this error in the console:

[image]

I've tried using xmlhttprequest and ended up with the same results... Could someone help me out?

Comment: Is what you get is valid `JSON`? What do you see when you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Either use `JSON.parse` or `jQuery.parseJSON()` not like `jQuery.JSON.parse`

Comment: Hello. This is what console says https://i.imgur.com/41Xcalr.png, and I did do JSON.parse, it said the same thing.

Comment: **Show the response the browser gets.**

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5FKYxof.png response and error, using the code.

Comment: jQuery will parse the response from JSON into a JavaScript object. You get the error because you are trying to parse a JavaScript object as if it were a JavaScript string containing JSON.

Comment: What? Dude that's no help.

Comment: @Ownslo read the comment by @Quentin, you don't need to do `jQuery.JSON.parse` since it's already a `JavaScript` object, `jQuery` automatically does that for you and returns the proper `JavaScript` object. Just access whatever properties you need - `data.whatever`...